# Node.js memory buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an interesting task and I decided to try solving it with Node.js. I am trying to output unique chunks of text file filled with quotes and random phrases (300MB) like this: split it in 50 line chunks and for every query it would give unique chunk. Chunks will be served in order. Server has alot of free ram (~30GB) and Node.js should sparkle here. Code in progress:

```
var lazy = require("lazy"),
    fs = require("fs");

new lazy(fs.createReadStream('huge.txt'))
    .lines
    .forEach(function(line) {
        var http = require('http');

        http.createServer(function(req, res) {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            });
            res.end(line.toString());
        });

    });

server.listen(8000);
```

Should switch to memory buffer with this:

```
var buffer = fs.readFileSync('huge.txt');
```

Any suggestions how to design this correctly?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what you're trying to do but probably the var http, and http.createServer should be situated outside of the forEach.

Comment: Yeah, I have semi-working version but I doubt anyone here cares for nodejs anymore :(